# My .profile and .bashrc files are not read

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

When I run `clang'I get the error message

```bsh
command clang not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install clang
```

Both `.profile` and `.bashrc` are not read.
Below is my `.profile` file

```bsh
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
source "$HOME/.cargo/env"

export DENO_INSTALL="/home/amani/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/clang/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/flutter/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/gradle/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/kotlinc/bin:$PATH"
```

and then my `.bashrc` file

```bsh
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u > '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
```

And below is my $HOME/.Cargo/env

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# rustup shell setup
# affix colons on either side of $PATH to simplify matching
case ":${PATH}:" in
    *:"$HOME/.cargo/bin":*)
        ;;
    *)
        # Prepending path in case a system-installed rustc needs to be overridden
        export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
        ;;
esac
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know that `.bashrc` and `.profile` files are not run? Are you sure of that? By any chance, does your `$HOME/.cargo/env` file contain an `exit` command? If yes, then this is what probably happens: `.profile` file is run, it sources `.bashrc`. `.bashrc` sets up the aliases etc., and at the very end it sources the `$HOME/.cargo/env` file, which somewhere executes the `exit` command, thus aborting any further processing. So the `.profile` file never proceeds to setting PATH etc. (cont.)

Comment: Also be warned that if you remove `exit` from the `$HOME/.cargo/env` file, you'll end up sourcing it twice - one time from `.bashrc` and the second time directly from `.profile`. This may give unwanted effects. Correct it so that the file is sourced only once.

Comment: @raj how do I correct it I'm not very conversant with these bash.

Comment: @raj I've added the `$HOME/.cargo/env` file.

Comment: You have the line `source "$HOME/.cargo/env"` in both in the `.profile` file and also in the `.bashrc` file. You need it in only one of them. You need to figure out in which file you want to keep it, And remove it from the other. Furthermore, you need to figure out, *after* which lines of code you want it being read. In other words, you need to determine at which point in the file it should be called.

Comment: Also: should it be all-lowercase `.cargo`, or with a capital letter `.Cargo`? check for consistency everywhere.

Comment: Btw. for system-wide environment variables that are seen by all programs `.profile` is the right file. `.bashrc` is always scoped to terminal windows. But since it's being read every time you open a terminal, its effect may appear omnipresent.